Any way to figure out the internet URLs of INetCache files?
Is it possible to find the URL associated with a cache file in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache? There are several SVG files that locating the origins from them on internet URLs would help. There are two ways I am wondering are possible:

INetCache files can be traced to a URL as they are being cached.

Monitor when INetCache files are being stored and see what URL is being requested when storing them.


